# How to check if string a exists in a specified column in database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

this is my sample access database:

ID--UserName--Password--AccountType

1---- A123    --1234    --User

2-----B123    --1345    --Admin

---

I am using VS2012.  In my VB.net Project I have username textbox, a password textbox,
and login button.

I add my database using a wizard.  I can add, modify, delete, and query, but how to check if the entered username in username text box exists in `UserName` column?

I filled up my dataset using:

```
Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.WSDataSet.users)
```

and if I want to get the user type I am using:

```
Me.WSDataSet.users.FindByUserName(IDtxt.Text).AcountType
```

but the main problem if user not exists I get the error below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in user login.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I check if the username exists or not?

Comment: Use `AccountType` instead of `AcountType`?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this.

```
 Dim user = Me.WSDataSet.users.FindByUserName(IDtxt.Text)

 If not user is nothing Then
     'Do what you want with the user object
 Else
     'Message User does not exist.
 End If
```

you just check if the user exists then do what you want with it.